# Error al ejecutar codigo con ListView, SelectedItems

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webservice, listview

Tengo una aplicación la cual consume varios servicios web.

Lo que intento hacer es una vez llamado este servicio el cual me debería proporcionar una lista de nombres de proyectos, quisiera agregarlos a un `ListView` y que el usuario pueda elegir que proyecto usar.

Al ejecutar mi código, obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.
```

Aqui esta mi codigo, podrian decirme como puedo hacerlo funcionar?

```
ProjectMetaData[] pr = GetProjectMetaData();

foreach (ProjectMetaData proj in pr)
{   
    var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(proj.ProjectID);
    listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);

}
projectTitle = this.listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index.ToString();
```

la variable projectTitle es un getter fuera del main:

```
string projectTitle { get; set; }
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Te da la excepción en esta linea? `projectTitle = this.listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index.ToString();` Si es asi, el problema es que no hay ningun item seleccionado, lo cual es logico ya que acabas de cargar los proyectos

Comment: Buen punto, pero si quiere afichar los proyectos en el listView, como deberia hacerlo?

Comment: Depende. Es un proyecto winforms?

Comment: Si es un winforms, y en el formulario el usuario tendria que ver los proyectos y poder seleccionar cual quiere usar

Comment: Entonces, suscribete al evento `SelectedIndexChanged` del `ListView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En principio, tu codigo de carga del `ListView` es correcto:

```
ProjectMetaData[] pr = GetProjectMetaData();

foreach (ProjectMetaData proj in pr)
{   
    var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(proj.ProjectID);
    listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);
}
```

Despues, si quieres detectar cuando el usuario seleccione un elemento de la lista, tendrias que hacer algo asi:

Primero, en el constructor del `Form` suscribirte al evento `SelectedIndexChanged`:

```
this.listView1.SelectedIndexChanged += ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

Y crear un metodo como este:

```
private void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    projectTitle = this.listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
}
```

Comment: si me resulto tal cual me sugeriste, muchas gracias!!